# Sequelize transactions become idle - PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I've been using sequelize on my projet & noticed a lot idle transactions (postgresql).

I've checked all my code & I always commit or rollback my transactions.
I pass the transaction object to my update, delete & create request
But not in my select request, would it be the reason why i have idle transactions please ?

Or is it possible i have idle transaction because i'm creating transaction this way :

```
const transaction = await databaseAdapter.sequelize.transaction();
```

and then pass my transaction object in some function params ?
which commit / rollback the transaction at the end of execution (commit at the end of the "try" section & rollback in the "catch") ?

any help is more than welcome